# Azure search complex struct sql datasource

Tags: azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

What would be a sql datasource for complex json result from azure search?

Azure search index can connect to single table/view of sql server. So if i have complex json what would the datasource table/view look like ?

for instance if resulting json is like this:

```
{
  "HotelId": "1",
  "HotelName": "Secret Point Motel",
  "Description": "Ideally located on the main commercial artery of the city in the heart of New York.",
  "Address": {
    "StreetAddress": "677 5th Ave",
    "City": "New York",
    "StateProvince": "NY"
  },
  "Rooms": [
    {
      "Description": "Budget Room, 1 Queen Bed (Cityside)",
      "Type": "Budget Room",
      "BaseRate": 96.99
    },
    {
      "Description": "Deluxe Room, 2 Double Beds (City View)",
      "Type": "Deluxe Room",
      "BaseRate": 150.99
    },
  ]
}
```

What would be corresponding sql datasource ?

Comment: How is this JSON stored in your SQL table/view? Is this the value of a particular column or is this a whole row?

Comment: This isnt stored in my table. I want to know how can it be used with SQL as datasource

Comment: Will you consider json result as this : {
  "hotelid": 1,
  "name": "hotel1",
  "hoteldetails": [{
    "hc": "city1",
    "hs": "st1",
    "room": [{
      "type": "type1",
      "description": "desc1"
     }, {
      "type": "type2",
      "description": "desc2"
     }, {
      "type": "type3",
      "description": "desc3"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }

Comment: Yes this works for me. What would be its corresponding sql datasource ?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the “Rooms” field in your example below it seems you want to **combine several rows** from the source SQL table into an array field in a single Azure search document – unfortunately combining multiple rows into a single field of a document is not supported.

For other fields, like “Address”, it seems you want to **combine several columns** (of the same row) into a single field, which is possible using the [Shaper skill](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/search/cognitive-search-skill-shaper):

I hope this helps.